# navigation stack SendingSimpleGoals Tutorial

Tags: ros, navigation, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to run on our differential drive robot with the navigation stack.I am using cturtle 1.2.4.the tf transform in my setup is map->odom->base_link->base_laser.However When i am giving the initial pose using rviz to make the robot to be on map the odom frame is not moving with respect to the base_link.It is staying at the same place as before.However the laser frame is transforming properly.I am not able to give the goal to the robot.When i used sending goals through code the following error is showing
"The base failed to move forward 1 meter for some reason".As far as i understand the localization is working fine.So where I am going wrong?Thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9474/navigation-stack-sendingsimplegoals-tutorial/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-18**:
yes I am using the same code to send goals..

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-18**:
So you are using the code from http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals to send goals?

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-18**:
no we have build the robot ourselves and also written the drivers.The drivers are working fine because we are able to  operate it using joystick.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Is this a custom robot or are you using an existing driver to provide access to the robot itself (such as p2os or rosaria)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With your updates to the question the error you are getting says that the move base action failed.  Do you have 1 meter of free space in front of the robot?  Try it with a smaller distance defined.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-27**:
i will try that and reply u back.Thank you for the suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like perhaps your `base_link->odom` transform is not updating. Does the robot move in rviz if you joystick or push it around?

The [Robot Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) tutorial has details on setting up an example odometry source.

A good sanity check for whether or not your odometry is working correctly is to joystick the robot around with the following rviz configuration:

```
 set the fixed_frame to odom
 set the decay_time on the laser scanner's topic to something very large (1000 or so should do)
```

If your odometry is working properly (and is accurate), you should get something that looks like a map of your environment. If you don't get anything like that, there is definitely a problem with your base_link->odom transform.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-18**:
@eric i am getting a map which is looking somewhat like my environment...So my odom->base_link transform is correct?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-18**:
@avin111: @tfoote has a good point (that I missed when reading your comment). See REP 105 for details on the coordinate frames used: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html . See update to answer for more debugging steps.

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-18**:
@tfoote i am computing my odom using encoders.As said before the odom frame is grouping into red lines when it is moving forward.even the robot moves along with this.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-18**:
You say that the odom frame "moves with" the base link which is not what it's supposed to do.  The odom frame is supposed to stay approximately stationary while the robot moves around.  How are you computing your odom?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Since the Joystick works, can you check the output on /cmd_vel (or whatever you may have remapped the cmd_vel topic to) when the navigation stack is trying to execute a goal? Also, do you get any output in, say, rxconsole, from move_base when it "fails to move forward 1 meter"?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-18**:
@avin111: Since debugging the navigation stack will likely involve lots of back and forth, can you make sure to update the question to include all the extra info from this and the comment above (and any other future comments that add more info to the question)? This will keep things better organized

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-03-18**:
i have tried moving using joystick .the odom frame is moving along with the base_link frame when i am using joystick.but when i am trying to give a goal in rviz it is not working.